# Unable to load the image on imagebutton on create method

Tags: android

I have to load an image for image button on create.I wrote the below code.The image is not loaded when it comes in the UI.What am i doing wrong.This is my master activity and i am inheriting this in another activities.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
setContentView(R.layout.activity_master_page);  
TheContext = this;  
ImageButton ThePosLogoL=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnposlogo);  
ThePosLogoL.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smalllogo);
```

Here is my button Layout

```
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/btnposlogo"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@null"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

Comment: remove android:background="@null"

Answer (score 2):

```
ThePosLogoL.setImageResource(R.drawable.smalllogo);
```

Comment: Put staatic image in xml file and check whether it is disply or not

Comment: thats working,my problem is i have to change the image to the one read from the database.... I am trying to use the same code in another class which inherits this master class..and it works